# itextsharp table chart legends beneath bars

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Can someone explain me how I can create chart like this one using itextsharp library.

[image: legend table is attached to graph, with years for each bar]

As you can see here, this chart has attached table with legends to its bottom side. And each bar has year attached to it. I want to create something like that.

[image: legend table is not attached to graph: Chart I created]

Second picture. This is what i have so far. I don't have year attached to each bar, and my legends are not beneath each bar like in top graph. If someone could guide me how to create identical graph like one on top i would be grateful. Thanks in advance!

[image: I added each year to each bar: I have this now]

How can I turn those labels to be displayed horizontally, and put those legends beneath years in table like one in picture number 1.

```
        // Chart Centers By Year
        var chartCentersByYear = new Chart
        {
            Width = 1000,
            Height = 450,
            RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag,
            AntiAliasing = AntiAliasingStyles.Graphics,
            TextAntiAliasingQuality = TextAntiAliasingQuality.High


        };

        chartCentersByYear.Titles.Add("Centers By Year");
        chartCentersByYear.Titles[0].Font = new Font("Arial", 16f);
        chartCentersByYear.Titles[0].Alignment = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopLeft;

        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas.Add("");
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;


        chartCentersByYear.Series.Add("Count");
        chartCentersByYear.Series.Add("Cases");
        chartCentersByYear.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column; //Pie
        chartCentersByYear.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StepLine; //StepLine
        chartCentersByYear.Series[1].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
        chartCentersByYear.Series[1].BorderWidth = 3;

        chartCentersByYear.Series[0].Color = Color.Brown;

        chartCentersByYear.Legends.Add("1");
        chartCentersByYear.Legends.Add("2");

        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].HeaderSeparator = LegendSeparatorStyle.Line;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].HeaderSeparatorColor = Color.Black;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].ItemColumnSeparator = LegendSeparatorStyle.Line;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].ItemColumnSeparatorColor = Color.Black;

        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].HeaderSeparator = LegendSeparatorStyle.Line;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].HeaderSeparatorColor = Color.Black;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].ItemColumnSeparator = LegendSeparatorStyle.Line;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].ItemColumnSeparatorColor = Color.Black;

        //For the Legend  
        LegendCellColumn firstColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
        firstColumn.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.SeriesSymbol;
        firstColumn.HeaderBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].CellColumns.Add(firstColumn);
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].CellColumns.Add(firstColumn);

        LegendCellColumn secondColumn = new LegendCellColumn();
        secondColumn.ColumnType = LegendCellColumnType.Text;
        secondColumn.Text = "#LEGENDTEXT";
        secondColumn.HeaderBackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;

        LegendItem newItemCount = new LegendItem();
        newItemCount.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, "Count", System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
        newItemCount.BorderWidth = 1;
        newItemCount.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;

        LegendItem newItemCases = new LegendItem();
        newItemCases.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, "Cases", System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
        newItemCases.BorderWidth = 1;
        newItemCases.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;

        // Getting data from a stored procedure  
        var totalCentersByYearResult = new Repository().GetTotalCentersByYear();

        foreach (IGD_spInternationalReportCenterWithTots1_Result item in totalCentersByYearResult)
        {
            // For Series
            chartCentersByYear.Series[0].Points.AddXY(item.YearEcmo, item.Count);
            chartCentersByYear.Series[1].Points.AddY(item.Cases);

            // For Legend
            newItemCount.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, item.Count.ToString(), System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);
            newItemCases.Cells.Add(LegendCellType.Text, item.Cases.ToString(), System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter);

        }

        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(newItemCount);
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].CustomItems.Add(newItemCases);

        chartCentersByYear.Legends[0].Docking = Docking.Bottom;
        chartCentersByYear.Legends[1].Docking = Docking.Bottom; //Top

        chartCentersByYear.Series[0].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        chartCentersByYear.Series[1].YAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;

        //For two coordinate systems
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.LineColor = Color.Transparent;
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
        chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY2.IsStartedFromZero = chartCentersByYear.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.IsStartedFromZero;            

        using (var chartimage = new MemoryStream())
        {
            chartCentersByYear.SaveImage(chartimage, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            Byte[] newChart = chartimage.GetBuffer(); //return chartimage.GetBuffer();

            var image = Image.GetInstance(newChart); //Image.GetInstance(Chart());
            image.ScalePercent(50f);
            image.SetAbsolutePosition(document.LeftMargin + 40, document.BottomMargin + 100);

            document.Add(image);
        }
```

Comment: ... and how exactly do you expect anyone to help you without any source code, modus operandi, and overview of things you've tried ?

Comment: I have added the code. I thought it will only confuse people. I hope you can help me now. Thanks for your correction about the code.

Comment: `Chart` is not an iTextSharp class. Thus, there is no easy automatic way for iTextSharp to know where exactly to put table columns. Does that `Chart` class somehow provide the x coordinates of all the bars and *y* axis?